# drag and drop multiple divs

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I have two `<div>` tags. One has several `<div>` tags of different sizes and positions and must drag them to another div. However, I need to drag back to the previous div, changing X and Y according to where I drop it.

How do I do this using HTML5?

Comment: I'll explain what I need.
M working with optimization of glass, ie have a split which represents the glass sheet where several small pieces are
positioned. The idea is that the user can change them in place, trailing the play (div) to another div which is adjacent to the larger sheet for later
drag it back and drop it in another position.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <style>
    #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
    #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this )
                    .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
                    .find( "p" )
                        .html( "Dropped!" );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div style="color:#0000FF">
  <h3>This is a heading</h3>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
    <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
    <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, by code.
It would be almost that. Indeed, divs can not be on top of another

Comment: I'll explain what I need.
M working with optimization of glass, ie have a split which represents the glass sheet where several small pieces are
positioned. The idea is that the user can change them in place, trailing the play (div) to another div which is adjacent to the larger sheet for later
drag it back and drop it in another position.